# Why I need to have an build script on package.json to deploy something on Now? and How can I fix it?

Tags: node.js, json, express, deployment, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy some expressjs code to Now like this video show me, specially this part https://youtu.be/aqiJQaPDy7o?t=2942 and I get some error like this:

> C:\Users\username\Desktop\forum\server>now
>   Deploying ~\Desktop\forum\server under username
>   Using project server
>   Error! Your `package.json` file is missing a `build` property inside the `script` property. More details:
>   https://zeit.co/docs/v2/advanced/platform/frequently-asked-questions#missing-build-script
>
> C:\Users\username\Desktop\forum\server>

I must create a script to build? Why? I am sending a json on my main express route, I don't have an interface. In the video, he has no build script, because he is creating the front end on VueJS.

How can I fix it?